# Setting image to anchor tag not working

Tags: html, css

I want to set image to anchor tag but it is not working. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

```
<a href="#" style="width:200px;height:100px;background:url('@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/facebook.png")');"></a>
```

**Note:** Don't pay attention to background. It is Asp.Net MVC syntax. But rest assured the image is loaded correctly. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? If I type something in anchor tag it works fine. But I don't want to type anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either set the display property to block or inline-block for the link

```
<a href="#" style="display:block; width:200px;height:100px; ...
```

Links are inline by default.

Answer (score 3):

Because a link is an inline element, it can't have width and height.

Set this attribute on it:

```
display: inline-block;
```